# Guardar en una variable un nombre y apellido que ingrese el usuario

Tags: c++

Necesito hacer un programa en el que el usuario introduzca su nombre completo, su edad, y que imprima en pantalla:

> "Señor" nombre "su edad es" edad

Estoy aprendiendo cadena de caracteres, pero no sé muy bien cómo usarlas.

Código *C++*:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

main() 
{
    int edad;
    char nombre[50];

    cout<<"ingrese nombre \n";
    cin>>nombre;

    gets(nombre);
    cout<<"ingrese edad \n";
    cin>>edad;

    if (edad>=0&&edad<=9){ cout<<nombre<<" su piso es 0 \n"; }
    if (edad>9&&edad<=19){ cout<<nombre<<" su piso es 1 \n"; }
    if (edad>19&&edad<=29){ cout<<nombre<<" su piso es 2 \n"; }
    if (edad>29&&edad<=39){ cout<<nombre<<" su piso es 3 \n"; }
    if (edad>39&&edad<=49){ cout<<nombre<<" su piso es 4 \n"; }
    if (edad>49&&edad<=59){ cout<<nombre<<" su piso es 5 \n"; }
    if (edad>59&&edad<=69){ cout<<nombre<<" su piso es 6 \n"; }
    if (edad>69&&edad<=79){ cout<<nombre<<" su piso es 7 \n"; }     
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Hola! Aqui en Stack Overflow no hacemos deberes. Tienes que intentar tú algo y si no consigues avanzar, te salen errores , preguntar aqui preguntas específicas con soluciones especificas. Esto es *demasiado amplio*

Comment: Estás aprendiendo cadenas de caracteres... ¿Te refieres a la clase `string`? ¿arrays crudos... `char cadena[100]`? Cada opción tiene sus propias características. Como imagino que tu respuesta será la segunda, te puedo garantizar que cualquier manual de C te servirá en este caso.

Answer (score 5):

Primero de todo la fución `main()` en c++ tiene que **retornar siempre un entero** si queremos seguir los estándares del lenguaje. Puedes mirarte lo que dice la documentación sobre esto [aquí](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function).

Por otro lado no debes importar bibliotecas que no uses por lo que eliminamos `string.h`.

En cuanto al problema en si, supongo que tu dolor de cabeza viene porque quieres capturar un `string` con espacios, por ejemplo `Pepito Pérez García`. La captura con `cin` tiene el problema que al encontrar un espacio se detiene por lo que solo te capturará el nombre pero no los apellidos.

Existen funciones para hacer esto, `gets()` si no me equivoco está marcada como ***deprecated*** en `c++` y eliminada de `c` en el estándar de 2011. Podemos usar en su lugar [`cin.getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline).

Por otro lado, te recomiendo que cambies tus `if` por `else if`. La diferencia es que si todos son `if` los evalua todos siempre, si usas una estructura `if, else if, else` cuando una condicón se evalue como cierta las restantes se ignoran, siendo más eficiente.

El código quedaria algo así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int edad;
    char nombre[50];

    cout<<"ingrese nombre \n";
    cin.getline(nombre,sizeof(nombre));

    cout<<"ingrese edad \n";
    cin>>edad;

    if (edad>=0&&edad<=9){ cout<<nombre<<" su piso es 0 \n"; }
    else if (edad>9&&edad<=19){ cout<<nombre<<" su piso es 1 \n"; }
    else if (edad>19&&edad<=29){ cout<<nombre<<" su piso es 2 \n"; }
    else if (edad>29&&edad<=39){ cout<<nombre<<" su piso es 3 \n"; }
    else if (edad>39&&edad<=49){ cout<<nombre<<" su piso es 4 \n"; }
    else if (edad>49&&edad<=59){ cout<<nombre<<" su piso es 5 \n"; }
    else if (edad>59&&edad<=69){ cout<<nombre<<" su piso es 6 \n"; }
    else if (edad>69&&edad<=79){ cout<<nombre<<" su piso es 7 \n"; }

   getch();
   return 0;
}
```

Si tienes libertad es mejor que en vez de un array de caracteres uses la biblioteca [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) que facilita y hace más seguro el trabajo con cadenas en `c++`. Para ello puedes usar[`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)para capturar la cadena:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int edad;
    string nombre;

    cout<<"ingrese nombre \n";
    getline(cin,nombre);

    cout<<"ingrese edad \n";
    cin>>edad;

    if (edad>=0&&edad<=9){ cout<<nombre<<" su piso es 0 \n"; }
    else if (edad>9&&edad<=19){ cout<<nombre<<" su piso es 1 \n"; }
    else if (edad>19&&edad<=29){ cout<<nombre<<" su piso es 2 \n"; }
    else if (edad>29&&edad<=39){ cout<<nombre<<" su piso es 3 \n"; }
    else if (edad>39&&edad<=49){ cout<<nombre<<" su piso es 4 \n"; }
    else if (edad>49&&edad<=59){ cout<<nombre<<" su piso es 5 \n"; }
    else if (edad>59&&edad<=69){ cout<<nombre<<" su piso es 6 \n"; }
    else if (edad>69&&edad<=79){ cout<<nombre<<" su piso es 7 \n"; }

    getch();
    return 0;

}
```

Yo eliminaria el uso de `conio.h` al no ser una biblioteca estandar y habiendo funciones que hacen lo mismo que `getch();` en ella, pero esto no es incorrecto, solo son preferencias.

Comment: 50 bytes de char reservados para nada? que pasa si se me ocurre poner algo demás, yo haría algo como:                                                               `char* buffs = new char[sizeof(buffs)]; cin.getline(buffs, strlen(buffs)); `

Comment: @nikomaster tienes razón pero mi ejemplo es para su código y el declara un array estático, por supuesto que usar memoria dinámica puede ser mejor pero viendo su código posiblemente esté aprendiendo y no me parece apropiado meterse en reserva y liberación de memoria y demás cuando no es ese su problema y ni siquiera usa punteros en su código. Y ya puestos, usamos string, que para algo está en c++ y del que si le doy un ejemplo de ello.

Answer (score 0):

**Gracias por solucionar mi problema, aunque solamente acomodé el orden del código, ya que ésta solución se ejecutaba pero no me incluía el nombre solo me imprimía en pantalla la edad, así es como debería quedar el código.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

int edad;
char nombre[50];

using namespace std;


int main()

{
cout<<"ingrese nombre \n";
cin>>nombre;

cout<<"ingrese edad \n";
cin>>edad;

if (edad>=0&&edad<=9){ cout<<nombre<<" su piso es 0 \n"; }
else if (edad>9&&edad<=19){ cout<<nombre<<" su piso es 1 \n"; }
else if (edad>19&&edad<=29){ cout<<nombre<<" su piso es 2 \n"; }
else if (edad>29&&edad<=39){ cout<<nombre<<" su piso es 3 \n"; }
else if (edad>39&&edad<=49){ cout<<nombre<<" su piso es 4 \n"; }
else if (edad>49&&edad<=59){ cout<<nombre<<" su piso es 5 \n"; }
else if (edad>59&&edad<=69){ cout<<nombre<<" su piso es 6 \n"; }
else if (edad>69&&edad<=79){ cout<<nombre<<" su piso es 7 \n"; }
else if (edad<0){cout<<nombre<<" esta edad no existe \n";}
getch();
return 0;
}
```